# React-Redux-Saga TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null

Tags: react-redux, redux-saga

Please lemme know I'm stuck past 3 days.I'm newbie to Redux Saga I'm not understanding where I'm going wrong. As I've just started dont have much experience, not understood the sagas that well:( .But I wanna get onto it.

I need to show sales data in line graph following is my code

Sample Json Data

```
{"data":[{"year":"2014","Sales":4390,"Orders":3800},{"year":"2013","Sales":4490,"Orders":4300},{"year":"2015","Sales":2200,"Orders":3400},{"year":"2016","Sales":1280,"Orders":2398},{"year":"2017","Sales":5000,"Orders":4300},{"year":"2018","Sales":4780,"Orders":2908},{"year":"2019","Sales":5890,"Orders":4800}]}
```

Admin Folder

adminActions.js

```
                import {GET_SALES_DATA} from '../constants/actionTypes';
                export const getSales =()=>({
                type:GET_SALES_DATA
                });
```

adminReducer.js

```
                import {GET_SALES_DATA,SALES_DATA_RECEIVED} from '../constants/actionTypes';

                const adminReducer=(state={},action)=>{
                    switch(action.type){
                        case GET_SALES_DATA:
                            return {...state};
                        case SALES_DATA_RECEIVED:
                            return {...state,payload:action.salesDataPerYear}  **//issue here   payload data is not received state is not getting updated with the data**
                        default:
                            return state;
                    }
                }

                export default adminReducer;
```

adminSaga.js

```
                import {put,takeLatest,all} from 'redux-saga/effects';
                import {GET_SALES_DATA,SALES_DATA_RECEIVED} from '../constants/actionTypes';

                function *getSales(){
                console.log("5saga")
                const salesDataPerYear=yield fetch("api call")
                    .then(response=>response.data);


                yield put({type:SALES_DATA_RECEIVED,salesDataPerYear:salesDataPerYear})
                }


                function *actionWatcher(){
                yield takeLatest(GET_SALES_DATA,getSales)
                }

                export default function *rootSaga(){
                yield all([
                    actionWatcher(),
                ]);
                }
```

dashboard.js

```
                const mapStateToProps=(state)=>({
                data:state.salesDataPerYear
                })

                const mapDispatchToProps = {
                getSales:getSales
                };


                class DashboardMain extends React.Component {

                componentDidMount(){
                this.props.getSales()
                }

                render() {
                const { classes,data } = this.props;
               // const  { data } =this.state;
                **console.log(data)// data not rendering in console is the saga i've written is correct?**

                return (
                <div className={classes.root}>   
                    <Grid container spacing={24}>
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <SimpleLineChart data={data} />**//commented**
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <SimpleTable /> 
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </div>
                );
                }
                }

                DashboardMain.propTypes = {
                classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
                };

                const Dashboard=connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(DashboardMain);
```

simleLineChart.js (UPDATED)

```
    <LineChart data={ this.props.data }> **// TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined**
```

Following is store folder

```
  index.js

            import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
            import {createStore,applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
            import {logger} from 'redux-logger';
            import rootSaga from '../adminDashboard/adminSaga';
            import reducers from '../adminDashboard/adminReducers';

            const sagaMiddleware=createSagaMiddleware();

            const store=createStore(
            reducers,
            applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware,logger),
            );

            sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

            export default store;
```

Data is not shown in line chart.I know there's some error in my saga but I dont know what is it :(.

Can anyone please lemme know where I'm going wrong. Anything which I've missed onto. Any help is appreciated.

Updates

Data not rendering in console is the saga I've written is corrector I've missed onto something?

```
                undefined
                redux-logger.js:389  action GET_SALES_DATA @ 12:38:06.302
                redux-logger.js:400  prev state {}
                redux-logger.js:404  action     {type: "GET_SALES_DATA"}type: "GET_SALES_DATA"__proto__: Object
                redux-logger.js:413  next state {}
                adminSaga.js:7 5saga

                            Response {type: "cors", url: "API call", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}body: (...)bodyUsed: falseheaders: Headers {}ok: trueredirected: falsestatus: 200statusText: "OK"type: "cors"url: "API call"__proto__: Response
                            redux-logger.js:389  action SALES_DATA_RECEIVED @ 12:38:07.103
                            redux-logger.js:400  prev state {}__proto__: Object
                            redux-logger.js:404  action     {type: "SALES_DATA_RECEIVED", payload: Response, @@redux-saga/SAGA_ACTION: true}payload: Responsebody: (...)bodyUsed: falseheaders: Headers {}ok: trueredirected: falsestatus: 200statusText: "OK"type: "cors"url: "API call"__proto__: Responsetype: "SALES_DATA_RECEIVED"@@redux-saga/SAGA_ACTION: true__proto__: Object
                            redux-logger.js:413  next state {payload: undefined}payload: undefined__proto__: Object
```

I've commented the simpleLineChart there some issue with the saga and reducer I dont get the result.I updated with the log please check. the API call is retriving the data. But in reducer I'm doing wrong which I've no idea.Please lemme know

Comment: Perhaps, in the dashboard.js  `const  { data } =this.state;` is a problem line. You map global state to PROPS, rather than to STATE of a component. So this `const  { data } =this.props;` should work.

Comment: @RussCoder know I get the props type error in simpleLineChart.js .Please check Ihave update the code

Comment: And what is `this` in simpleLineChart.js ? In what component is that line written?

Comment: @RussCoder I've commented that  simpleLineChart component. i updated with the log please check. the API call is retriving the data. But In reducer I'm doing wrong which I've no idea

Comment: You seemingly don't know how fetch() works. 
Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response 
There isn't any data property in response object, you should invoke a method, like .json() or text() rather than return plain non-existing `data` property.
I'm speaking about this line
`const salesDataPerYear=yield fetch("api call").then(response=>response.data);`

Comment: @RussCoder yeah i dint knew. But then thats it worked.I have update my question

Answer (score 0):

It worked like a charm horray:)  after three days ufff .I learnt much worthy.the saying goes true to me "We learn more from our mistakes" Thanks to @RussCoder

adminSaga.js

```
                    try{
                        const salesDataPerYear=yield fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/78b9w")
                                .then(response=>response.json())
                        yield put({type:SALES_DATA_RECEIVED,payload:salesDataPerYear.data})
                    }
```

adminReducer.js

```
                    case SALES_DATA_RECEIVED:
                    return {...state,payload:action.payload };
```

dashbord.js

```
   const mapStateToProps=state=>{
      return{   
        dataSales:state  //have changes data to dataname
      }
     };
```